# upgrade to ubuntu 15.04 along with windows 7 without losing data

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, 15.04, windows-7

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 version on my desktop along with windows 7. But, now i want to upgrade my ubuntu to 15.04 version. How can i upgrade without losing my data on my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

There are risks of loosing your data when upgrading Ubuntu from a version to an other.

The only way to resolve this problem is to backup your data before performing the upgrade. If you do not want to backup your data into USB stick or burn them on a CD/DVD then you can save the data directly on your Windows session without using an external memory because from Ubuntu you can access to your Windows session.